# Animate back to original style

Tags: jquery, css

If I have this:

```
.circle {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I can animate scaling it bigger like this:

```
$('.circle').animate({
    'height' : 40px,
    'width' : 40px,
    'border-radius': 20px
});
```

But what is the best way to then downscale it back to it's original css (using an animation, so just stripping the inline html style won't work)?

I can think of two ways:

- If the css is fixed (it's not in my case) then I can just animate it back using hard-coded values
- If the css is not fixed, I can store each original attribute in a variable before making it bigger, then use those values to scale it back down again.

The downside of the second method is a lot of variables and lines of code needed if there are several fields.

I'm not expert at jQuery and I think there must be an easier way I'm missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to use CSS for setting the presentation layer and toggleClass in jQuery to add and remove CSS properties by toggling a class.
In this case using jQuery `toggleClass()` instead of `addClass()` and `removeClass()` avoids the use of an if else statement to check if the class `.animated` is already present to the `.circle` class.

**JS / jQuery**

```
$('.circle').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('animated');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   border-radius: 100px;
   transition: all .5s ease;
   background-color:red;
}

.circle.animated {
   height: 400px;
   width: 400px;
   border-radius: 200px;
   background-color:blue;
   transition: all .5s ease;

}
```

I edited the dimensions of the circle to make it more visible and change the background color too. If you click it you will see the transitions applied by CSS.
This way you will keep your code clean, and it will be much easier to edit by editing the CSS properties of each class.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/eNUpJ/12/

***Good rule of thumb:***

**HTML** for structure 
 **CSS** for presentation 
 **JS (or jQuery as JS framework)** for behaviour

Comment: Yes i know, of course css transitions are not supported in old browsers. Good point. It's also true that it's since several versions of most of browsers css transitions are supported. Click on all browser versions at this link: http://caniuse.com/css-transitions

Comment: @iStimple If you use an old browser, you don't deserve good things.

Comment: @bjb568 I agree with you and I know what you mean, but is also true that if you are working on most commercial projects, like for instance e-commerce or such, unfortunately when you see the requirements you start crying when reading IE8 and even very old versions of mobile android native browser :D

Answer (score 3):

Put your transition directly afterward.

```
$('.circle').animate({
    'height' : 40px,
    'width' : 40px,
    'border-radius': 20px
},'fast', function(event) {
$('.circle').animate({
    'height' : 20px,
    'width' : 20px,
    'border-radius': 10px
}'slow');
```

Comment: Avoid using jQuery for editing CSS properties. It's more convenient adding and removing a class with CSS properties applied to it instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $(".circle").animate({
        "height": "40px",
         "width": "40px",
         "border-radius": "20px"
    }, {
        duration: 2500,
        done: function (promise) {
            var back = {};
            $.each(promise.props, function (key, value) {
                back[key] = String(Number(value.replace("px", "") / 2) + "px");
            });
            return $(this).animate(back, promise.duration);
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/5vY2s/

See
http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options